# Python - changing a 10 digit phone # to words with a list #Simplicity

Tags: python, list

So i'm not too sure how to proceed with this.
I want to replace `1` with `one`, `2` with `two` and so on.

I'm supposed to do this with a list.. but I'm not sure how to do so.

The user inputs a 10 digit number, which gets re-arranged into a phone number and then dashes are added in the appropriate areas.

I have completed the first two parts but can't figure out the conversion to 
words.

Edit** I am saying this is not a duplicate due to the fact that I was looking for a simple method to doing this. Every other thread I looked at contained coding beyond the level of understanding that I possess.

```
def makePhoneNums():
    original = getNumber()
    phone_num = fixPhoneNum(original)
    phone_word = getWordForm(phone_num)
    printPhoneNums(original, phone_num, phone_word) 

def getNumber():
    original = input("Input a 10 digit number: ")
    while 10 != len(original) or original.isdecimal == False:
        original = input("Error! Input a 10 digit number!: ")
    print()
    return original

def fixPhoneNum(original):
    switched = original[-1] + original[5:9] + original[1:5] + original[0]
    phone_num = switched[:3] + '-' + switched[3:6] + '-' + switched[6:]
    return phone_num

def getWordForm(phone_num):
    words = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
             'eight', 'nine']
    s = '0123456789'
    telNum = ''
    for i in range(len(s)):
        telNum += words[int(s[i])]
    return words[i]

def printPhoneNums(original, phone_num, phone_word):
    print(original, '\t', phone_num, '\t    ', phone_word)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues in your code -

1. Main issue, in your `getWordForm()` function, you create the string with words as `telNum` , but then you return `words[i]` , you should return the `telNum` and you should iterate over `phone_num` the argument to your function, not `s`. Please note this would not include any spaces between the words, a better way to do this would be to use `' '.join()` if you want spaces. Example -

   ```
   def getWordForm(phone_num):
       words = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
                'eight', 'nine']
       return ' '.join([words[int(ch)] if ch.isnumeric() else ch for ch in phone_num])
   ```

   You need the condition `if ch.isnumeric()` because you are sending in the fixed phone number (with `-` inbetween) , if you do not want spaces you can simply use `''` (empty string) for `str.join()` .

   As asked in comments, a method without using `str.join()` -

   ```
   def getWordForm(phone_num):
       words = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
                'eight', 'nine']
       result = ''
       for ch in phone_num:
           if ch.isnumeric():
               result += words[int(ch)] + ' '
           else:
               result += ch + ' '
       return result[:-1]
   ```

   Please note, the method without `str.join()` would not include spaces, I would recommend using `str.join()` over this.
2. Secondary issue , you should call the function `isdecimal` in `getNumber()` , as - `while 10 != len(original) or original.isdecimal() == False:`

Comment: So this code you've provided does work. However, I haven't used .join, ch, etc yet. The specifications I need to follow includes staying within my level of understanding. Is there a more introductory way of doing this?

Comment: Do you need spaces between the words? Or even better would be to understand how `str.join()` works, its easy and a powerful tool.

Comment: Yes, I need spaces between both the words and the dashes. It's just that I haven't had str.join() demonstrated in class and if I use it I would be docked marks for doing the lab which should be completed using what I've already been taught in class.

Comment: @CameronRogozinsky - Why would you be docked marks for using a method the class hasn't taught you yet? Is it because it would heavily imply that you didn't do your own homework?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 This is my first experience with computer programming. I have been doing my homework but frankly this lab is the hardest of the semester, both my Lab instructor and my professor have said so. Please tell me that when you started out you didn't feel overwhelmed at times.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you seem to be returning the wrong thing!

```
def getWordForm(phone_num):
    words = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
             'eight', 'nine']
    s = '0123456789'
    telNum = ''
    for i in range(len(s)):
        telNum += words[int(s[i])]
    return telNum  # <== return telNum here
```

Furthermore, you seem to not be using `phone_num`. I don't think you need `s` there at all. So:

```
def getWordForm(phone_num):
    words = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
             'eight', 'nine']
    telNum = ''
    for digit in phone_num:
        telNum += words[int(digit)]
    return telNum
```

I'm not sure if you mean to but spaces between the words, but it should be  easy to figure out.

Comment: Using this method I simply got the output of: 'one'

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
call = lambda s: ' '.join(map(lambda c:['oh','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','niieeiieeine','-'][int(c) if c.isdigit() else -1],s))
```

For a good time:

```
>>> print(call('8675309'))
eight six seven five three oh niieeiieeine
```

Alternative one-liner from [PM 2Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4014959/pm-2ring):

```
call = lambda s: ' '.join([['oh','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','niieeiiee‌​ine','-'][int(c) if c.isdigit() else -1] for c in s]
```

Prettier IMO, but unclear if it's more efficient:

```
In [75]: timeit.timeit("lambda s: ' '.join([['oh','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','niieeiiee‌​ine','-'][int(c) if c.isdigit() else -1] for c in s])('8675309')",number=200000000)
Out[75]: 17.842306826962158

In [76]: timeit.timeit("lambda s: ' '.join(map(lambda c:['oh','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','niieeiieeine','-'][int(c) if c.isdigit() else -1],s))('8675309')",number=200000000)
Out[76]: 17.543266678927466
```

Comment: Cute (although you're showing your age with that Tommy Tutone ref :) ). OTOH, `lambda s: ' '.join([['oh','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','niieeiieeine','-'][int(c) if c.isdigit() else -1] for c in s])` is marginally shorter & avoids the `map` function call. Also, `map` in Python 3 returns an iterator, which `join` needs to convert to a list, since `join` has to make two passes over its arg (the 1st pass is to calculate the destination string size). So it's slightly more efficient to pass `join` a list comp than an iterator or generator.

Comment: @PM2Ring, glad someone got it. :) Agreed that your version is cleaner looking, but the two versions are within margin of error of each other, timing-wise. Updated my answer with timing.

Comment: It's hard to get true timing data from stuff like this. I _suspect_ that the time to build the number words list is not negligible relative to the time it takes for the list comp to loop over 7 digits. Of course, you could pre-build that list, but then it wouldn't be a [one-liner](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287631/4014959). ;) And there will probably be a speed difference running it on Python 3 vs Python 2, for the reason I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Probably so. Nice discussion all the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> words = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
>>> phone_number="123 1234 123"
>>> '-'.join([words[int(num)] for num in list(phone_number) if num.isdigit()])
'one-two-three-one-two-three-four-one-two-three'
```

Or map solution,

```
>>> '-'.join(map(lambda x: words[int(x)] if x.isdigit() else '', list(phone_number)))
'one-two-three--one-two-three-four--one-two-three'
```

In the function

```
def getWordForm(phone_number):
    words = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
    return '-'.join([words[int(num)] for num in list(phone_number) if num.isdigit()])
```